# Python JSON formatting

Tags: python, json, formatting, openweathermap

So I have a problem with JSON. The data that I receive from an API looks like this.

```
{
    "weather":[
       {
          "id":804,
          "main":"Clouds",
          "description":"overcast clouds",
          "icon":"04d"
       }
    ]
 }
```

I can't read the data in the weather cell tough because it's wrapped between those '[ ]'. But if I try to create a JSON file but remove the "[ ]" and try to read it, it works. What can I do? Please help!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I do the following it works just fine:

```py
import json

data = '''{
    "weather":[
       {
          "id":804,
          "main":"Clouds",
          "description":"overcast clouds",
          "icon":"04d"
       }
    ]
 }'''

dict_data = json.loads(data)
print(dict_data.get("weather")[0].get("main"))
>>> "Clouds"
```

It works as expected. Because it is a list, you have to target the first item, here another dict, which holds the information you want.

Comment: Glad I could help :)